Powershell script not running from task scheduler
Currently, I have developed a PowerShell script which collect CSV files from NAS drive and copy the files to the local server. I am able to execute the script manually also able to run from PowerShell console successfully.
But same script is not working when using windows task scheduler.  I have checked for enough permission on the local server. Also tried running the task scheduler on SYSTEM account but same issue is occurring.
Error output:
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20240702082116
Username: MS\SYSTEM
RunAs User: MS\SYSTEM
Configuration Name: 
Machine: server (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_serverstats.ps1
Process ID: 336
PSVersion: 5.1.17763.5830
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.5830
BuildVersion: 10.0.17763.5830
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1

Transcript started, output file is D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_powershell_output.log
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_serverstats.ps1:11 char:13
+ $csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.csv | Where-Obj ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\:String) [Get-ChildItem], 
UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_serverstats.ps1:11 char:13
+ $csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.csv | Where-Obj ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauth
   orizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\' because it does not exist.
At D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_serverstats.ps1:11 char:13
+ $csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.csv | Where-Obj ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\:String) [Get-ChildItem], 
ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\' because it does not exist.
At D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_serverstats.ps1:11 char:13
+ $csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.csv | Where-Obj ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Script execution completed
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20240702082116

PowerShell query:
Start-Transcript -Path "D:\NWATCH_Automation\nwatch_powershell_output.log"
# Define the source and destination directories
$sourcePath = "\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH\"
$destinationPath = "D:\nde_automation3\"
# Get the current date and time
$currentTime = Get-Date
# Calculate the time one hour ago
$oneHourAgo = $currentTime.AddHours(-2)
# Find CSV files in the source directory that were modified in the last one hour
$csvFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter *.csv | Where-Object {
   $_.LastWriteTime -ge $oneHourAgo
}
# Check if the destination folder exists, if not, create it
if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $destinationPath)) {
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationPath
}
# Empty the destination folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationPath | Remove-Item -Force
# Copy unique CSV files to the destination folder
foreach ($file in $csvFiles) {
   $destinationFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $file.Name
   # Check if the file already exists in the destination folder
   if (-Not (Test-Path -Path $destinationFile)) {
       Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destinationFile
       Write-Host "Copied $($file.Name) to $destinationPath"
   } else {
       Write-Host "Skipped $($file.Name) as it already exists in the destination folder"
   }
}
Write-Host "Script execution completed"
Stop-Transcript


Just at a glance $sourcePath = "\nasdrive\prod\NWATCH" will most likely not work because you have it running as system. System doesn't know what that directory is when the script launches. You should fully qualify or map a letter to the directory before using it in the script. You can use new-smbmapping cmdlet or net use to map z: to \nasdrive first. Ex New-SmbMapping -LocalPath 'Z:' -RemotePath \\nasdrive\  'Then, you can change your $sourcePath variable to have a value of Z:\prod\NWATCH

Please, format properly your question, as is it's unreadable.

Have you tried scheduling with whether user is signed on or not and then type in the credential of the account it works when you run the script manually.
